# Route::resource does not support auth:api

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication, laravel-passport

I use **passport** for **api authentication** and i configure auth.php api gaurd  to **passport**.
 Some of my route APIs are in auth:api group. I send Authorization header with access token and it check user very well.

But the problem is that, this mechanism works well in Route::post method and \Auth::user()->id return user id,

> but in Route::resource \Auth::user() returns null.

I double checked everything and it seems Route::resource ignore "auth:api" middleware. I also tested middleware in __construct method of my resource controller. Nothing changed. Thank you for further help.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']],function (){
    Route::post('update',['uses'=>'C_Update@handle']);
    Route::resource('contacts','C_Contacts',['only'=>['index','store','update','destroy']]);
});
```

Comment: `Route::resource` literally isn't doing anything more than registering the 7 routes you could manually register.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last i found a solution. The problem was because of __construct method. The Authenticated user hasn't been Authorized in construct method yet (I don't know why and if someone knows please tell me). So unfortunately I put \Auth::user in CRUD functions of my route.

Comment: because authorization is handled by a middleware. the middleware stack hasn't ran by the time the constructor for the controllers have been ran. it needs to get an instance of the controller so it can see what middleware the constructor might have registered.

Comment: Oh I don't know that sequence. Thank you for clarifying. @lagbox